# Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ an application $f(x)=|x|^2x$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ an application defined by the rule $f(x)=|x|^2x$, where $|\cdot|$ and the euclidean norm, $| x | = \langle x,x \rangle.~$ Show that $f$ is of class $C^1$ (i) and carry a unit ball $B(0,1)$ over herself injectively. (ii) Show, ask, that your inverse is not differentiable at the origin (iii).

(i) To prove that $f$ $\in$ $C^\infty$, I did it like this:

I know that the standard function is class $C^\infty$ and also the identity function is class $C^\infty$. Logo $f$ is a product of functions that are class $C^\infty$ So $f$ is class $C^\infty$.

(ii) To show that $f$ takes an open ball of radius 1 centered injecting itself on the origin ... I don't know how to prove it ... looking at the function of the impression of actually being a normalized ball. Any help in that part?
How do I show that you have a ball in a ball. Did you understand the reasoning of this.

(iii) Finally, prove that $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable in origin. I thought of assuming that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable in origin, I thought of using the trick $f^{-1} \circ f = x$, so if we derive, $Df^{-1}(f(x)) Df(x)=1$. Then I don't know what I can do.

Comment: By the standard function you mean $x \mapsto |x|$?  Be careful as this is not differentiable at zero.

Comment: Also, I assume you mean $|x| = \sqrt{x_1^2+ \cdots + x_n^2}$ (which is different from what you wrote).

Comment: Be careful since the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ you cannot say "$Df^{-1}(f(x))Df(x)=1$" unless $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

For (ii), you need to show that the restriction of $f$ to $B(0,1)$ is injective and has image contained in $B(0,1)$.  Injectivity is easy: $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $|x|^2x = |y|^2y$.  Writing $x = (x_1, ... , x_n)$ and likewise $y$, look at what the equation $|x|^2 x = |y|^2y$ is saying at each entry to conclude that each $x_i = y_i$, hence $x=y$.

To show that the image of $B(0,1)$ is contained in $B(0,1)$, you need to show that if $|x| \leq 1$ then $|f(x)| \leq 1$.  In other words, you need to show that $||x|^2x| \leq 1$.  Positive numbers can come out of the norm (that is, $|c \cdot x| = |c| |x|$ for all $c \in \mathbb R$ and $x \in \mathbb R^n$).

For (iii), do you have a formula for the inverse of $f$?  Where does $f^{-1}$ send any nonzero element of $\mathbb R^n$?  Where does it send $0 = (0, ... , 0)$?

Comment: I fully understood item (ii) that you explained. In item (iii) Yes we have a formula for the inverse, then I derive and replace the zero, my guess is that it will zero. If it is zero why can I conclude that f will not be differentiable?

Comment: Try the case $n=1$.